# Where can I find UML diagrams (instead of reinventing the wheel)?

Tags: repository, diagram, uml, analysis-patterns

I am currently trying to draw a set of UML diagrams to represent products, offers, orders, deliveries and payments.  These diagrams have probably been invented by a million developers before me.

1. Are there any efforts to standardize the modeling of such common things?  Or even the modeling of specific domains (for example car-manufacturing).
2. Do you know if there is some sort of repository containing UML diagrams (class diagrams, sequence diagrams, state diagrams...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a movement for documenting (as opposed to standardizing) models for certain domains. These are called **analysis patterns** and is a term Martin Fowler came up with. He actually wrote a book called [Analysis patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201895420). Also, he has a [dedicated section](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles.html#id22541) on his website where he presents some of these patterns accompanied by UML diagrams.

Maybe you'll find some **inspiration** that will help you in modeling your domain. I've stressed the word inspiration as I think different businesses have different requirements although they operate the same domain so the solutions you might read about may not be appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are many tools out there that do both - but they're generally not free!
Microsoft Visio does both and is extensible.  For UML artefacts they come with auto generators into VB/Java template code - but you can modify them to auto-generate any code.  There are many users of Visio that have created models from which to use as templates.

Artisan Enterprize is by far the most powerful UML tool (but it's not cheap).

Some would argue that Rational Rose or RUP is the better tool

But for Car-Manufacturing and other similar real world modelling, by far the best tool is Mathworks Simulink (not because it's one of the most expensive).  It is by far the best tool beccause you can animate the model - you can prove the model working before generating the slik code (in whatever grammar/language/other Models you care to push it)!
You can obtain a student license for around £180; with the 'real thing' pushing £4000 (for car-related artefacts).  The full product with all the trimmings is about £15k.  Simulink is also extensible with a C like language though there is a .Net addin and APIs to use a plethora of other langhuages.  And, just like Visio there is a world-wide forum creating saleable, shareware & freeware real world model templates.  Many world-wide Auto-Manufacturers are already using Simulink.

Answer (score 0):

I think that MiniQuark question is really good and will sooner or later be provided by vendors such as Omondo, Rational IBM etc... Users doesn't just need tools, they need models out of the box and just add their business rules inside an existing well defined architecture. Why to develop from scratch a new architecture if the job has already be done ? In Java we use plenty of frameworks, existing methods etc...so why not to go one level higher and reuse architecture ? It is today impossible to guess how a project will evole and new demands are coming every day. We therefore need a stable architecture which has been tested previously and is extensible. I have seen so many projects starting with a nice architecture then realizing in the middle of the project that this is not what is the best and then changing their architecture. Renaming classes, splitting classes, creating packages etc...after the first iteration it is getting a real mess. Could you imagine what we found after 10 iterations !! a total mess !!
This mess would had been avoided if using a predefined model which has been tested previously because the missing class, or package etc..would have already been created and only a class rename would be sufficient for architecture purposes. Adding business rules methods will end the codding stage before deployment test.

I think there is a confusion between patterns and the initial question which is related to UML model re usability.
There is no today any reusable model out of the box which has been developped. This is really strange but the job has never been done or never been shared. 
Omondo has tried to launch an initiative without real success. I have heard that they are working on hundred of out of box models which will be open source and given for free to the community. I hope this will be done because this is really important for me and would save me a lot of time at the beginning of a project.

Comment: Don't be confused by what is a model. A model for Omondo is a single model per project, composed by multiple packages and diagrams. A model could not be just a diagram because a diagram is for me just a view of the model in specific configuration and not the model itself. I have seen an interesting opposition between Ed (e.g. EMF) and Vlad (Omondo) because for Ed modeling is a view of a problem and for Vlad modeling cover full project. Reusable models are only possible if model cover full project and not just a view of a problem !!